# Miles Johnson's file uploader generates empty files

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, uploader

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.6 and just added Miles Johnson's image uploader. 
Everything seems to work when I use my View to upload a photo I get a success return.
A file gets created with the right name, so formatName function seams to work.
But the **size** of the created **file is always only 56bytes**. No matter how big the originally uploaded file was.

I have the strong feeling that there is something wrong with user rights or with configuration of apache server that it maybe does't alow upload.

Does anybody know what could let me create a file but not put content into this file?
On the [Uploader Howto](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader#faq-6) there is nothing said about any changes I would have to do on apache or php configuration.

**View:**

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Site');
    echo $this->Form->input('startpageImage', array('type' => 'file'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

**Model:**

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Uploader.Attachment' => array(
        'startpageImage' => array(
            'tempDir' => TMP,
            'finalPath' => '/img/uploads/',
            'nameCallback' => 'formatName',         
        )
    )
);
public function formatName($name, $file) {
    return sprintf('%s-%s', $this->field('id'), $name);
}
```

Comment: Something to try - first find your phpini file using:
`php -i | grep php.ini`
and then modify the parameter:
`upload_max_filesize = xxM` where xx is a suitable value.

Comment: Thanks, I checked this but it already was at 2M and even 96kB pictures failed to upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a email to Miles Jones and he found the mistake immediately:

**View:**

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Site', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('startpageImage', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

I forgot the

> , array('type' => 'file')

in the first line of Form.
No black magic, no rocket science... :)

Comment: And if you've already got an array there, you need to merge them: `array('type' => 'file'), array('role' => 'form')` needs to become `array('type' => 'file', 'role' => 'form')`. It won't accept two arrays.